# How can I change Mvc Routing spaces like "%20" to "-"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

My current routing is like `https://localhost:44312/Games/Sea%20of%20Thieves`.

I want to change as `https://localhost:44312/Games/Sea-of-Thieves`.

I'm working on `.Net Core Mvc` Project. Any ideas ?

```cs
[Route("Games/{gameName}")]
public IActionResult GameDetail(string gameName)
{
    Game requestedGame = _unitOfWork.Games.GetGameByName(gameName);
    GameDetailModel gameDetailModel = _unitOfWork.Games.GetGameDetail(requestedGame.Id, User.Identity.Name);
    return View(gameDetailModel);
}
```

Comment: Show your controller code

Answer (score 0):

You should replace spaces with `-` when you create a link on your web site.

For example you can create an interface that replace `space` with `-`. then inject the interface on your view or place you create link.

```cs
public interface IUrlHelper
{
    string RemoveSpace(string url);
}
public class UrlHelper : IUrlHelper
{
    public string RemoveSpace(string url)
    {
        return url.Replace(" ","-");
    }
}
```

in your view or anywhere you create a link you should use this interface

```
@inject IUrlHelper urlHelper
<a href="@urlHelper.RemoveSpace(YourUrl)">TestUrl</a>
```

**Note :** remember that register `IUrlHelper` in services.

Comment: It has to come with spaces into the controller but at [Route("Games/{gameName}")] I want to change spaces into "-" in gameName.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware in startup Configure:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var url = context.Request.Path.Value;

                if (url.Contains("/Games/")&&url.Contains(" "))
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(url.Replace(" ", "-"));
                    return;
                }

                await next();
            });
```

result:
[image]